# RichFaces LiveSearch on inputField

Tags: jsf, process, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I am using RichFaces and want to implement a live search on my website. I got an input field, and a div which got built dynamically in my backing bean. Actually, the method bean.getResultsDiv() calls setResultsDiv() and creates the MyFaces Div object in consideration of the searchString. Unfortunately if I type one char in my input field, the rerendering of the results-div happens too early and the searchstring won't be updated. How to make sure that processing of the char happens first and then the bean-method for creating the new result-div got triggered? Thanks in advance.

```
<t:inputText id="mysearchString"
    value="#{bean.searchString}"
    onkeydown="jQuery('form_processSearchString').click();"
/>
<4j:commandButton id="processSearchString" 
    process="mysearchString"
    reRender="results"
/>
<t:div id="results" binding="#{bean.resultsDiv}" />
```

UPDATE-1: I debugged and now I can see that bean.searchString is updated correctly. Unfortunately the getter-method for getResultsDiv() is called before setSearchString(newStringToSeach). How can I make sure that the processing happens first and then the rerendering.

Another code snippet I am playing around with (same behaviour, rerendering-getter-call is triggered before setSearchString()):

```
<t:inputText id="searchString"
    value="#{beans.searchString}"
    onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false; }">
    <a4j:support event="onkeyup" requestDelay="200" ajaxSingle="true"
        reRender="resultsDiv" eventsQueue="quicksearchqueue"
        ignoreDupResponses="true"
        process="searchString" 
    />
</t:inputText>
```

Thanks for help!

UPDATE-2: I was able to find out that the getter of the corresponding binding did not get triggered at all and so there is no chance that the div will get updated. That seems the problem!

```
<t:div id="results" binding="#{bean.resultsDiv}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you going good finding through. 
Note the attribute `listener` binding to the `process` method that is the trick in this sample.
each *keypress* in search string `txtSearchString` should be tracked and `process` method need to called. And this will update the *Ajax live search panel* below input control.

Facelet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
</h:head>
<body>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="txtSearchString" value="#{lively.seStr}">
            <f:ajax event="keypress" render=":result" execute="@form" listener="#{lively.process()}"/>                
        </h:inputText>
    </h:form>
    <h:outputFormat id="result" value="#{lively.liveMsg}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Mmanaged bean:

```
import javax.inject.Named;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

import java.io.Serializable;

 @Named(value = "lively")
 @SessionScoped
 public class lively implements Serializable {

private String seStr = "";
private String liveMsg = "....";
private int livelyID = 0;

public String getLiveMsg() {
    return liveMsg;
}

//public void setLiveMsg(String liveMsg) {
//   this.liveMsg = liveMsg;
//}

public String getSeStr() {
    return seStr;
}

public void setSeStr(String seStr) {        
    this.seStr = seStr;
}

public lively() {

}

public void process() {
    //initialize
    if (seStr.length() == 0) 
        livelyID = 0;

    //access the search string        
    liveMsg = seStr + " - ";

    //do some work
    livelyID++;
    if (livelyID <= 10) {
        liveMsg = "less than 10";
    } else if (livelyID > 10 && livelyID <= 20) {
        liveMsg = "more than 10";
    } else {
        liveMsg = "more than 20";
    }
 }
}
```

Just add the bean and facelet to a JSF project and run the facelet.

Sorry but I don't have *prime faces* I work on pure Glassfish implementation but you might find this sample interesting which works similar to your requirement.